# Kubernetes ingress connnection types and specific connection

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

On Kubernetes, I want the first connection to be the pod using less CPU, and the incoming connections to be sticky sessions. How do I do this?

I try this and sticky session support, but I want first connection must come to least connection,least bandwidth or something.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "stickounet"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-service-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Using load balancer like nginx or treafik your request will automatically be routed to pod or node with less resource utilization rates and this [document](https://docs.ovh.com/asia/en/kubernetes/sticky-session-nginx-ingress/) describes the process of configuring sticky connection in a step by step procedure.